# How to get the latest data which is unique in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, typescript

I have original data like this in an array arr

```
[
{Id:1,
Date:20/06/2023,
ProdId:1
},
{Id:2,
Date:21/06/2023,
ProdId:1
},
{Id:3,
Date:21/06/2023,
ProdId:2
},
{Id:4,
Date:23/06/2023,
ProdId:2
},
{Id:5,
Date:20/06/2023,
ProdId:3
}
]
```

I want the items with unique prodIds and it should be latest. I should get the below data

```
[
{Id:2,
Date:21/06/2023,
ProdId:1
},
{Id:4,
Date:23/06/2023,
ProdId:2
},
{Id:5,
Date:20/06/2023,
ProdId:3
}
]
```

What do I need to do?

Comment: Added answer. please refer the below for the working code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm sure there is probably an easier way, but this worked for me:

```
    this.customers.sort((a, b) =>
      new Date(b.Date) > new Date(a.Date) ? 1 : -1
    );
    var uniqueCustomers = this.customers.filter((value, index, array) =>
      array.findIndex((c) => c.ProdId === value.ProdId) === index
    );
    console.log(JSON.stringify(uniqueCustomers));
```

This code first sorts by the date. Then filters for unique values based on the `ProdId`.

Answer (score 0):

```
const myArray = [
  {Id:1,
  Date:20/06/2023,
  ProdId:1
  },
  {Id:2,
  Date:21/06/2023,
  ProdId:1
  },
  {Id:3,
  Date:21/06/2023,
  ProdId:2
  },
  {Id:4,
  Date:23/06/2023,
  ProdId:2
  },
  {Id:5,
  Date:20/06/2023,
  ProdId:3
  }
];
```

Trick:

```
const modifiedArray = myArray.filter((item, idx, array) =>
          array.findLastIndex((c) => c.ProdId === item.ProdId) === idx
    );
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

This function gets any proid and returns an object of same proid from myArray with latest date

```
function filterByProId(ProId: number){

    const filtered = myArray.filter((e:any) => e.ProId==ProId); //filter array by ProId
    var latest = filtered[0]; // get first item
    filtered.forEach(function(item){
       //get item with date greater than previous
       latest = (new Date(item.Date) > new Date(latest.Date)) ? item : latest; 
    })
}
```

Use Function filterByProId:

The function below parameter `end` and `start` defining the range of objects to return in the final array

```
function gettill(end: number, start: number = 0){
    finalArray: any[] = [];
    for (let i = start; i < end; i++) {
        // push latest item with ProId = i to the final array
        finalArray.push(filterByProId(i)); 
    }
    return finalArray; //the filtered array returned
}
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

### This can be achieved via an array `filter` method along with array `findLastIndex()` method.

### Refer below for the working sample code:

```js
const myArray = [{Id:1,Date:20/06/2023,  ProdId:1 },{ Id:2,Date:21/06/2023,PodId:1,Id:3,Date:21/06/2023,ProdId:2},{Id:4,Date:23/06/2023,ProdId:2},{Id:5,Date:20/06/2023,ProdId:3}];

const modifiedArray = myArray.filter((item, idx, array) =>
     array.findLastIndex((c) => c.ProdId === item.ProdId) === idx);

console.log(modifiedArray)
```